# When does FAB's color depend on colorAccent?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme, floating-action-button, material-components-android

According to [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionButton), the color of the view defaults to our theme's `colorAccent`. I tried changing `colorAccent` in my styles resource file, but nothing happened:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">#d81b60</item>
</style>
```

So I tried changing `colorSecondary` instead:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorSecondary">#d81b60</item>
</style>
```

And it worked. So my question is does it really depend on `colorAccent`? If yes, when?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting with the [version **`1.1.0`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.1.0-rc02/lib/java/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/res/values/styles.xml#L40) of the Material Components Library the default style of the `FloatingActionButton` is based on **`?attr/colorSecondary`**:

```
  <style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton" parent="Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton">
    <item name="backgroundTint">?attr/colorSecondary</item>
  </style>
```

Starting with the version [**`1.2.0`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.2.0-alpha04/lib/java/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/res/values/styles.xml#L40) of the Material Components Library the default style of the `FloatingActionButton` is:

```
    <style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton" parent="Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton">
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/mtrl_fab_bg_color_selector</item>
        <!-- .... -->
    </style>
```

**Starting from** the version **`1.2.0`** the `@color/mtrl_fab_bg_color_selector` is based on the **`?attr/colorSecondary`**:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorSecondary" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

In the version [**`1.0.0`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.0.0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/res/values/styles.xml#L23) the backgroundTint was based on **`?attr/colorAccent`**:

```
  <style name="Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="backgroundTint">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    ...
  </style>
```

Comment: Wow nice. The first link to version `1.1.0` is not working, though.

Comment: I should be thanking you. Thanks for clearing up the confusion. Is there a way to report this rather misleading info to the editor of the docs?

Comment: @Richard yes, you can file an issue on the [github repo](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues). I think that the documentation is still based on the 1.0.0 because the 1.1.0 is still in rc (not yet stable). In and case the source of the 1.1.0-1.2.0 is [still wrong](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionButton.java#L97). You can submit a PR.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, because the accent color is defined in the theme and themes are read-only in Android.

The only thing you can do is switch themes or set the color of each component manually.

**Note:** you can apply a theme to a portion of UI instead of the whole Activity in order to change the accent color (or other things) locally. To do so, you can use the android:theme attribute in your XML layout with the AppCompat library, or you can inflate a layout by providing a ContextThemeWrapper as context to your LayoutInflater.

**OR**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NewTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorOne</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorOneDark</item>
</style>
```

and inside the activity set theme

```
 setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NewTheme);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/profile_edit_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_white_24dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"/>
Notice it is:

app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
and not

android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"

Comment: This does not answer my question at all. I'm asking if it depends on `colorAccent`.

Comment: No, FAB is not depends on colorAccent only.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/floating-action-button/) you can read more:

> Component Attribute | Default Theme Attribute Value
>   - **backgroundTint** | colorSecondary
>   - **tint** | colorOnSecondary
>   - **rippleColor** | colorOnSecondary

or You can directly change it in XML with `app:backgroundTint`:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
    style="@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plus_24"/>
```